# Disable SQL escape in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I've tried

```
CacheConfiguration<?, ?> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheTemplateName).setSqlSchema("PUBLIC"); //create table can only be executed on public schema
cacheCfg.setSqlEscapeAll(false); //otherwise ignite tries to quote after we've quoted and there are cases we have to quote before ignite gets it
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
ignite.addCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg); //required to register cacheTemplateName as a template, see WITH section of https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table
```

Unfortunately nothing I try seems to work.
I've debugged through and `isSqlEscapeAll()` always returned true.
FYI in the `CREATE TABLE` statement I've set `TEMPLATE=MyTPLName`.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour? My queries are already appropriately quoted.

Comment: Why the vote to close and downvote? Is there information missing/could be added or is the question unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag doesn't work for dynamic caches since it could cause some unclearness with table names, which were described in this thread on Ignite dev list: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Remove-deprecate-CacheConfiguration-sqlEscapeAll-property-td17966.html

By the way, what is the problem you want to solve using this flag?

Comment: We generate SQL (tables and queries) from models. Field names in the models can be SQL keywords so when generating every name is generated as a SQL quoted identifier. As it turns out quoting works as expected. I initially thought it wasn't because the error msg would have things like `""fieldName""` around all quoted identifiers so I initially thought the syntax error was as a result of it being quoted again. Not the case, the generated SQL actually had a typo but the parser seems to catch it out of context so the resulting error is misleading I think.